# How to make Web Services public

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, web, service, amazon-ec2

i created an android application that requires use of web service
i want it to be able to access the app everywhere therefore i need 
my web services to be public with an external ip so i can access

what is the best way to do it?
I have an Amazon Web Services account i dont know if created an instance and run the web services there will be the best solution 
My big problem with Amazon instance is that it takes a while to show in the app the result of the web service

Any ideas in how to make my web service public?

Comment: An AWS EC2 server with an Elastic IP would be public. Your "big problem with AWS" sounds like you are doing something wrong, that is not a known issue with AWS.

Comment: Could it be by the type of instance: like t2.nano, t2.micro ?

Comment: The server type could certainly be causing slowness, if your application needs a larger server. You haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone to help you with that though, and it would probably require some application profiling on your end to determine the bottleneck. Anyway, that is another subject for another question you should open on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Expose a public API endpoint for use by your Android application
- Run some code when the API is called

There are two ways you could expose an API:

- Use [Amazon API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html), which that can publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs. It takes care of security and throttling. A DNS name is provided, which should be used for API calls. When a request is receive, API Gateway can pass the request to a web server or can trigger an **AWS Lambda** function to execute code without requiring a server.
- Or, run an **Amazon EC2 instance** with your application. Assign an **Elastic IP Address** to the instance, which is a static IP address. Create an `A` record in Amazon Route 53 (or your own DNS server) that points a DNS name to that IP address.